# Non-Gorenstein projective maximal Cohen-Macaulay module

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

In http://s.web.umkc.edu/segal/papers/refl.pdf the authors gave the first example of a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module $M$ (that is a module over an algebra A with $Ext^{i}(M,A)=0$ for all $i \geq 1$) that is not Gorenstein projective for a finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$ . However, the authors had to assume that the field is infinite.

Question: Can such a thing also occur for finite field?

Comment: You should clarify your definition of maximal Cohen–Macaulay here, since there are many options which are not in general equivalent: I guess you mean in the Buchweitz sense, so an $R$-module $M$ is MCM if $\operatorname{Ext}^i_R(M,R)=0$ for all $i>0$.

Comment: @MatthewPressland ok, I added the definition.